# Delete and Insert throws Duplicate entry for key PRIMARY

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mysql-5.7

I have a composite PK, where I need to update one of its PK value. But due to some internal issues, I can't fire update queries to a PK column.

So I'm firing **DELETE** and **INSERT** query.

This `DELETE` and `INSERT` is done inside a `TRANSACTION` (READ COMMITTED).

But sometimes, when two requests do update to the same row. On Duplicate entry for key `PRIMARY` errors are thrown. This occurs randomly, I tried a lot in reproducing this issue locally but I couldn't find the root cause.

Note: 
Due to some internal restrictions, I couldn't try the following things.

1. Update query to PK
2. Replace query
3. Insert on duplicate or Insert Ignore queries
4. Adding a running ID currently for this table will be a huge migration.

Kindly help me with this issue.

**Update:**

Sample Table Structure:

```
       Table: temp
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `id1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id1`,`id2`,`id3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Sample Data:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| id1 | id2 | id3 | value |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   1 | 100 | 111 |   123 |
|   2 | 200 | 222 |   456 |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Sample Queries:

Transaction T1 tries `to update ID1=3 value where id2=100`

```
Delete from temp where id2=100
Insert into temp values(3,100,111,123);
```

Transaction T2 tries `to update ID1=3 value where id2=100`

```
Delete from temp where id2=100
Insert into temp values(3,100,111,123);
```

number of deletion and insertion will always be the same

Comment: mysql 5.7 with innodb should atleast support online ddl so the InnoDB tables will not go down check the manual

Comment: @RaymondNijland couldn't get. Can you explain in detail.

Comment: maybe your problem is different. could you place some CREATE TABLE statements and the queries you execute then it is more clear what you mean or where your problem might be but at first seight you could try to set transaction isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, not sure without seeing code if it would fix your problem or not

Comment: Are you sure a) DELETE+INSERT runs in a transaction b) The table is InnoDB?

Comment: @akuzminsky  Yes it runs inside a transaction. And it is INNODB

Comment: @vinieth why you can't use just `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: How can you prove it?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Can't use that as well updated in note. My main issue is why some like this is happening

Comment: @akuzminsky A print is put in log when transaction is created and transaction roll back statement was also able to see in log.

Comment: @vinieth I think posting `CREATE TABLE` + a few `sql queries` from different workers will be very helpful

Comment: @DanilaGanchar updated the sample table structure and queries by changing column name and values.

Comment: The `DELETE` may remove multiple rows, correct?  And you are putting only one row back in, correct?

Comment: @vinieth, that's not good enough. Let me be straightforward. It's unlikely InnoDB fails to maintain an exclusive lock in a transaction, it's more likely something goes wrong when your app deals with the database. That's why you shouldn't trust your intended logic, you should prove facts to yourself to figure out what's wrong.
I would look into the general log to see that a BEGIN+DELETE+INSERT are a part of same session, so DELETE+INSERT are really executed in a same transaction.

If necessary, I'd go further and investigate what else inserted a row so your INSERT gets a duplicate key.

Comment: @RickJames If the delete is done for 3 rows.  Then I will insert new 3 rows. So number of deletion and insertion will always be same.

Comment: @vinieth - OK, based on that Comment (which is more precise than the Question), I am providing an Answer.  Please edit the Question to make that point clear.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, getting a duplicate key error (or for example deadlocks) once in a while is nothing fundamentally problematic. Database servers are inherently concurrent, and if you do not want to completely lock the database, it's expected that two processes may try to do something that conflicts each other (e.g. trying to insert the same row). It got caught, and your job is now to react to this properly.

For your situation, you should get your error when you do not have rows to delete (e.g. the id does not yet exists), which is especially likely if you use your logic of delete-insert generally even for completely new entries.

The [`read committed`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-committed)-isolation level does not keep locks for non-existing rows (or gap locks):

> For UPDATE or DELETE statements, InnoDB holds locks only for rows that it updates or deletes. Record locks for nonmatching rows are released after MySQL has evaluated the WHERE condition. This greatly reduces the probability of deadlocks, but they can still happen.

So without an existing row to delete, the following flow might happen occasionally for two transactions A and B that want to insert the same id:

```
A: delete id, no rows -> no lock
B: delete id, no rows -> no lock (and no wait)
A: insert id -> locks row(s)
B: insert id -> wait
A: commit
B: lock released -> insert id -> duplicate key error
```

Your details may vary, you may use some orm that hides those details, or you may e.g. have an additional check to see if that id already exists (but then you should include this check/select with `for update` inside your transaction to make this check consistent), and then use a different procedure that just inserts - but in that case you will just run into a similar problem: you will just get the duplicate key error in that other procedure (where two "simple" inserts conflict each other).

Ultimately, you will just have to handle the case that two sessions try do the same thing at the same time. As you excluded all solutions that handle this situation inside the database (e.g. `replace` or `on duplicate key update`), you will have to catch and handle it manually in your application (e.g. rollback and repeat the transaction).

You could test this by the way by changing your isolation level to `repeatable read` (but since this could be a significant change, you should only do this in a development environment). This should give you a deadlock instead of a duplicate key error for this situation. While this doesn't exactly solve your problem, it could convince you that this actually is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the delete-insert pairs are always paired up, use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..` instead of separate SQL commands.  This combines the steps into a single, atomic, operation.  Hence, it avoids the alleged issues of transactions.

The composite `PRIMARY KEY` together with the single-column specification for the `DELETE` is puzzling.  That implies that `Delete from temp where id2=100` may delete multiple rows.  So, the batching the delete is followed by multiple `INSERTs`?  That can be achieved by IODKU, and be as efficient, perhaps more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I mentioned in the note, I can't use IODKU

Comment: @vinieth - Perhaps IODKU inside a Stored Procedure?  What prevents use of it?

Answer (score 1):

@vinieth

As `id1`, `id2` and `id3` are the primary keys, there will be no chance to duplicate the value. right?

If your concern is just to update the `id1` then I would suggest you use `UPDATE` statement, instead of `DELETE` and `INSERT` statement. Because by doing delete and insert you are consuming the resource and it is a bad practice too.

You can simply write the statement as

```
UPDATE `temp`
SET
   id1=3
WHERE
   id2=100;
```

Instead of

```sql
Delete from temp where id2=100;
Insert into temp values(3,100,111,123);
```

You can see the difference between both statements.

Also If I talk about the error you are facing is just normal when it comes to bulk operation with DB.

DB engines are more intelligent. When you are fire both statements at the same time. DB will prepare the list of the statement before the execution. So, at that time of preparing the statement, It stays inside the Stack memory. And after the preparation of the query, they calculate the execution time and order them into the priority Just to make the execution faster. In that case, Your insert operation got the first priority. So, DB will try to execute the insert operation and found the value and throws a "Duplicate entry for PRIMARY KEY" error.

Solution: If you don't want to use `UPDATE` statement instead of `DELETE and INSERT`. Please remove the primary key from `id1` and check the result. But I still recommend you go with `UPDATE` statement.

EDIT:

There is also an another scenario that is responsible for this error.
When you trying to fire both queries at the same time. They both get to run in parallel. And as `DELETE` and `INSERT` both run at the same time, `INSERT` operation found the value which is yet to delete. And engine returns this error.

Comment: RDB engines will not, under any circumstances, ever, change the logical order of two statements in a session because they think that's faster. If there's absolutely no logical dependency, such an optimization (maybe: start the 2nd before the 1st is done) could theoretically be implemented, but it shall not ever result in a logically different outcome. Imagine the id doesn't exist: your proposal could randomly do "insert 1 row - delete 1 row = 0 rows" or "delete 0 row - insert 1 row = 1 row". And while I agree that an update is better, it's the 1st thing the op excluded as an option.

Comment: @Mayur  **INSERT operation found the value which is yet to delete. And engine returns this error**   Here INSERT will happen only when DELETE is done completely. How can it happen like this?

Comment: @Solarflare whats your call on this **INSERT operation found the value which is yet to delete.**

Comment: It is kind of locking. 2 operations need the same row.[at the same time]

Comment: @Mayur How 2 operation will need the same row. In my transaction INSERT is after DELETE operation.  So only when DELETE is done completely , INSERT operations will take place.

Comment: Agreed, But if this is your case, then why DB found the deleted row's value? and giving you the "Duplicate Value in Primary key" error. If DB gives you this error That totally meaning that your value is not deleted.

Comment: @vinieth I am not sure why you ask me what Mayur meant, but since I might have caused confusion with my comment, I'll clarify the comment: sql statements in a single(!) transaction are *by definition* serialized. Mayur had an idea about statement reordering, and I span this idea into a hypothetical feature. It's not implemented or planned yet, and may never be, as you can already do this by just opening a 2nd connection. In my opinion, you get the error due to two different(!) transactions which are NOT serialized against each other (but within themself). I tried to explain that in my answer.